# How to store data from a javascript code using PHP,SimpleXML?

Tags: javascript, php, html5-canvas, simplexml

I have a Javascript where I am able to draw on html5 canvas. Is it possible to store the coordinates of the drawings(say coordinates of a line that is drawn on canvas) in server?
Can i retrieve them when ever i want? I have searched for it and came across PHP, SimpleXml.
Is it possible to store the data using PHP and SimpleXml?? If so how to retrieve them. Please post any links that would help me.

Or is there anyother way other than simplexml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this (and save, and retrieve) for example through Ajax query to server.
For example, you can use jQuery library: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Ajax/ :
Also you can see [other helpful methods](http://api.jquery.com/?s=ajax), that are use above one. For example:
[jQuery.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) - for retrieve
[jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) - for save

Comment: Guess so. Let me see if anyone else replies with an other way. Appreciate your help.Could you like write a small code snippet. Im not able to understand whats there in that link.